# How convert RealmList to ReamResult

Tags: android, realm

I want use `RealmList` in a `RealmBaseAdapter` but it only accepts `RealmResult`.
How can I convert `RealmList` to a `RealmResult`?

Comment: You should pass the result, that from it you get the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently you would have to do something like this

```
realmList.where().findAll()
```

However we want to add a shared interface between the two making this easier. You can follow progress on that here: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/1363

Edit: From Realm Java 3.0.0 and Realm Android Adapters 2.0.0, this is no longer an issue, and `RealmBaseAdapter` works for both `RealmList` and `RealmResults`.